# There is a Design Pattern to name this solution?

Tags: php, algorithm, design-patterns

There is a solution that I use frequently, I would like to know if there is an design pattern that is related or next to this solution:

```
interface PhoneFormatterInterface {
    public function format($phone);
}

class BrazilFormatter implements PhoneFormatterInterface {
    public function format($phone) {
        //format a phone from +55 11 9 6666 2222 to (11) 96666-2222
    }

    public function isElegible($country) {
        //check if the country is right
    }
}

class PhoneFormatter {

    public $formatters;

    public function add(PhoneFormatterInterface $phoneFormatter)
    {
         //add formatters
    }

    public function format($phone, $country)
    {
          foreach ($formatters as $formatter) {
              if ($formatter->isElegible($country)) {
                  return $formatter->format($phone);
              }
          }
    }
}

class Client
{
    public function main()
    {
        $formatter = new PhoneFormatter();
        $formatter->add(...) //Add formatters, may we have some factory here

        $formatter->format('+55 11 9 6666 6666', 'BR');

    }
}
```

Can I name this solution with a known pattern?

Thank you!

Comment: try to explain the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Hi @IgnazioC thank you for replying, I want to format a phone number in the national format given an E164 format (its just an problem example), In my solution I added a class for each country following an interface, so in the client I iterave over this classes and chose the class depending on country. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example for the `strategy`design pattern, in addition you can create an `abstract factory` to create specific country phone formatters without scattering the complexity in all the code of your app.

Answer (score 0):

`Strategy` pattern and also can be `Dependency Injection` pattern

Here examples:
**Strategy**:
[Strategy pattern example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm)

**Dependency Injection:**
[Dependency injection pattern](http://www.journaldev.com/2394/dependency-injection-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial)